# how to make my program write logs with forever

Tags: node.js, logging, forever

I have a bash script, where I start my node.js program with

`node app/index.js > logs/QueueLog.out`. It works fine and writes logs to `logs/QueueLog.out` file.

But when I run it with forever

`forever start app/index.js > logs/QueueLog.out`

it does not write logs. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use these options:

```
 -l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
 -o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
 -e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

Here is the link:
https://github.com/foreverjs/forever